# Open Modal in React JS Application on Page Load automatically

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, bootstrap-modal

Below is the `App` class component in which I want to open Modal once the page gets loaded completely.

Also I tried using `componentDidMount()` lifecycle method but it failed.

```
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.handleSHow = this.handleShow.bind(this);
        this.state = {
            modalState : true
        }
    }

    handleShow = () => {
        this.setState(() => {
            return {
                modalState : false
            };
        });
    }

    render() {
        console.log(this.state.modalState)
        return (
            <div>
                <h1 className="main-title">My Profile</h1>
                <MainContent />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: share your model code also...or share complete code in sandbox

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that you're using [Bootstrap Modal](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/components/modal/), here is a basic example:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            modalState: true
        };

        this.handleShow = this.handleShow.bind(this);
    }

    handleShow() {
        this.setState({ modalState: !this.state.modalState });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div className={"modal fade" + (this.state.modalState ? " show d-block" : " d-none")} tabIndex="-1" role="dialog">
                    <div className="modal-dialog" role="document">
                        <div className="modal-content">
                            <div className="modal-header">
                                <h5 className="modal-title">My Profile</h5>
                                <button type="button" className="close" onClick={this.handleShow}>
                                    <span>&times;</span>
                                </button>
                            </div>
                            <div className="modal-body">...</div>
                            <div className="modal-footer">
                                <button type="button" className="btn btn-secondary" onClick={this.handleShow}>Close</button>
                                <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

And if you're using [react-bootstrap](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/), use like this:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            show: true
        };
        
        this.handleClose = this.handleClose.bind(this);
        this.handleShow = this.handleShow.bind(this);
    }
    
    handleClose (){
        this.setState({ show: false });
    };
    
    handleShow (){
        this.setState({ show: true });
    };
    
    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                <ReactBootstrap.Button variant="primary" onClick={this.handleShow}>Launch modal</ReactBootstrap.Button>

                <ReactBootstrap.Modal show={this.state.show} onHide={this.handleClose}>
                    <ReactBootstrap.Modal.Header closeButton>
                        <ReactBootstrap.Modal.Title>My Profile</ReactBootstrap.Modal.Title>
                    </ReactBootstrap.Modal.Header>
                    <ReactBootstrap.Modal.Body>...</ReactBootstrap.Modal.Body>
                    <ReactBootstrap.Modal.Footer>
                        <ReactBootstrap.Button variant="secondary" onClick={this.handleClose}>Close</ReactBootstrap.Button>
                        <ReactBootstrap.Button variant="primary">Save Changes</ReactBootstrap.Button>
                    </ReactBootstrap.Modal.Footer>
                </ReactBootstrap.Modal>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-bootstrap@next/dist/react-bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

For the correct answer, the Modal code is also required. We need to know what kind of modal you are using and how does it's toggle mechanism works.

However, looking at your code I have found a typo.

`this.handleSHow = this.handleShow.bind(this);`
Here in `this.handleSHow` the `H` is in Caps. So if you are calling the method to trigger the Modal's open state like so `this.handleShow()` then it will not work.

Either fix the typo or call the method like this: `this.handleSHow()`.

**Edit:** Looking again at your code I just realized you don't need `this.handleSHow = this.handleShow.bind(this);` this line because you are using arrow function syntax to declare your method i.e., `handleShow = () =>` . Arrow functions automatically bind the `this` context to your function from outer scope which in this case is your `App` Component itself so you don't need to `.bind(this)` in your constructor.

If you still want to keep `this.handleSHow = this.handleShow.bind(this);` then you have to change your arrow function `handleShow = () =>` to `handleShow() { ... }` syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this

```
class App extends React.Component {
constructor(props){
  super(props);
  this.handleSHow = this.handleShow.bind(this);
  this.state = {
    modalState : false
  }
}

componentDidMount(){
  this.setState({
    modalState : true
  }) 
}

render()
{
  console.log(this.state.modalState)
  return(
      <div>
      {this.state.modalState ? <YourModal/> : null}
      <h1 className="main-title">My Profile</h1>
      <MainContent />
      </div>
      )
}
}

export default App;
```

Comment: if using const App = props => { how to do?